# Advertising (ad mob) by screen or tabs?

Tags: android, google-analytics, admob, ads, firebase-admob

I have the follow situation:

1. One layout with TabLayout, ViewPager and advertising banner on bottom

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".ui.player.get.PlayerGetFragment"
    app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior">

    [...]

    <com.google.android.material.tabs.TabLayout
        android:id="@+id/tabLayout_player_get"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/materialCardView_player_get_header"
        app:tabMode="scrollable" />

    <androidx.viewpager2.widget.ViewPager2
        android:id="@+id/viewPager_player_get"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/tabLayout_player_get" />

    <com.google.android.gms.ads.AdView
        android:id="@+id/adView_player_get"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        app:adSize="BANNER"
        app:adUnitId="@string/player_get_banner_ad_id"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent" />

</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

2. Then AdMob documentation tell us about eCPM like follow:

- eCPM: The estimated earnings accrued for every 1000 impressions an ad generated by the AdMob Network received. eCPM doesn't represent how much an ad actually earned; rather, it's calculated by dividing estimated earnings by the number of impressions received, then multiplying by 1000.

> Formula: eCPM = ( Estimated earnings / # of impressions ) * 1000
>
> Example calculation
>
> If an ad earned an estimated $180 from 45,000 ad impressions, its eCPM
> would equal ($180 / 45,000) * 1000, or $4.00.

**My question: Is it better for me to display ads by screen or by tabs?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Is it better for me to display ads by screen or by tabs?**

eCPM doesn't change much with ad placement ( on same screen ), it will definitely have impact. Recommend to play around with admob placement on various screens and measure the performance of each advert by monitoring the analytics.

There are various other factors for eCPM calculation like Country where advertisement is displayed ( e.g. an advert displayed in USA vs ad displayed in India will have different eCPM value). You app category ( game vs education app or kids category app ).

Rather than thinking about eCPM. Always think from user perspective, loading lot of advertisement gives a bad user experience and app retention might be impacted with it. Also prevent placing ad where users might click it accidentally.

Refer to this guideline for Discouraged banner implementation.
https://support.google.com/admob/answer/6275345?hl=en&ref_topic=2936214

There are log of good resources provided by google to understand ad placement and how to boost your revenue with minimal disruption to end user.
https://admob.google.com/home/resources/

Also rewarded ad is another good option to explore for increasing the ad revenue.